# Using Chinese and Japanese characters as file name

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, cjk

I have developed a web application to upload and download files. Filename and file information are stored in database. Also, these files and other file information are displayed in a gridview. The website is localized for Chinese and Japanese languages.
I want the users to be able to enter Chinese and Japanese filenames as well. 
In Web.config file, I have entered this

```
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" fileEncoding="utf-8"/>
```

How can this be done? I read in some forums that Server.UrlEncode can be the solution, but how to use this in the application?

Please help!!

Comment: So what's the problem? What are you or aren't you seeing? 

The user's browser will take care of the IME character interface, so you don't need to worry about that. The only other thing (I can think of off the top of my head) to note is that the database columns are NVARCHAR, NCHAR or NTEXT to cope with the unicode format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works!!

I had thought this would be more complicated than this. But adding the above line in web.config and using nvarchar as the datatype for all the parameters in queries, it works!